# iOS: Control audio volume from within app and outside of app

Tags: ios, ios9, core-audio, audiotoolbox

Is it possible to manage the volume of audio from external source and internal source separately in iOS?

For example, if I am listening to Apple Music or iPod music and I launch into my app and play my own audio, is it possible to control the volume for the two separately?

Answer (score 1):

Generally you cannot control the volume of an app programmatically.  It's a safety thing.  Suppose you made a cool app that played sounds and you could programmatically crank the volume all the way up.

The only possible work around that I can think of is if you wrote your own player and lowered volume via a mixer/fader.  You could essentially decrease the volume but you could never go over the threshold volume level that the user set.

Comment: So it is possible to decrease volume of another app or background music while able to control volume of my own?